# Is it allowed to ask why a certain word ended up taking a meaning pretty different from its original one?

Tags: support, specific-question

I'd like to ask about how in lots of spanish speaking countries in South America the word "coger" ("to take" in English) ended as synonym of "having sex".

This word doesn't have any meaning like that in Spain, being the same as the word "to take" in English, also being a pretty common used word, and I personally cannot see how "to take" something could end up being related to "having sex".

Is such a question allowed?

Comment: I'm not sure that historical sources and methods will help with that.  Is there a Spanish language stack exchange?

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace, yes there is, but my point is asking how historically ended up being used like that, the same that there's historical evidence for certain expressions, I think there may be for that. Although I can post there if it fits better.

Comment: I'm not saying "no" - I'm just skeptical; I wish you luck

Comment: Have you tried asking this same question of the Linguistics.SE? I don't hang out there, so I honestly don't know how they'd answer. I do know that similar questions about English word etymology are often fielded on English Language & Usage SE.

Comment: Yeah, I'm with Mark. The problem you'd probably run into on this site is that its an officially English-language site, and there aren't likely a lot of resources on Spanish word etymology written in English. So while it may stay open, I'd be surprised if it got a lot of good answers. (I'm surprised quite often though...)

Comment: I agree, this is certainly technically on topic as history but you'd likely have better luck consulting Spanish specialists over at Spainish.SE: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks to everyone, I'll post there and let's see if I get lucky.

Comment: For everyone else reading along here, question was now asked and apparently well received here: https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35524/qu%C3%A9-hechos-hist%C3%B3ricos-produjeron-que-coger-tomara-el-significado-de-tener-se

Comment: I went to that link but didn't see any actual answer, plus I had to translate. That sounds like an interesting discussion. Languages evolve in some odd ways, particularly English since it manged to find its way to most corner of the globe and has some pretty cool history. Maybe you'll get a better response somewhere.

Comment: I concur with @ds_practicioner; though a seeming answer may have been posted, the development of a language is always a historic question.